# How to not initialise variable in GetxController from getX library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

In GetXcontroller, I need one variable named isOK that must not be initialised, because it's used to determine the selection of a widget, and I don't want any selection when app is opened.

When the variable is initialised, I can write that

`color: c.isOK.value ? AppTheme.selected: Colors.transparent`

But when it's not with `var isOK = Rx<Bool>;`
`c.isOK.value` is red underlined with the error: "The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'Type'".

And with `var isOk = Bool().obs;`, the error is "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'"

Have you any solution to encounter the problem. I thought about a local state variable to manage the selection and save it as global variable, but I'd like to do it with only global variable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use GetX Observables you need to define them as:

```dart
var isOK = true.obs;
//       OR
var isOK = RxBool(true);
```

This will automatically give it the type of RxBool.

For your case you need to initialise your variable as RxnBool. This observable can store three values: True, False and Null. You can pass a check in your widget tree then show the desired.

You can initialise the RxnBool as:

```dart
var isOK = RxnBool(null);
```

Assigning the value to the variable whenever required is same as RxBool.

```dart
isOK.value = false;
isOK.value = true;
isOK.value = null;
```

Apart from this if you do not want to use GetX you can always use a nullable and check if value is null or not then initialise it later before use;

```dart
Bool? someVar = null;
```

Comment: null is not accepted for initialisation as ```var isOK = RxBool(null);```

Comment: You need to use the RxnBool class you have used the RxBool class. Additionally could you provide the whole piece of code which is causing the error?

Comment: ok, I thought it was a typing error. It works, I just need to add a ! in the widget ```c.isOK.value!```